# How can I launch an application with PowerToys Run after changing the application file path?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, productivity, file-search, powertoys

I have an application in a folder on my Desktop. After changing the name of the folder, PowerToys Run cannot find it at the old address and is unable to run it from the most relevant search result.

In this screenshot of the Run window, if I click on the highlighted first result I get this error message.

Run window:

[image: screenshot of the Run window]

Error message:

[image: Error message]

...however clicking on the fourth result will open the app.

How can I change an application file path and have PowerToys Run find the correct path / update its search results?

Comment: What is the folder?  I have Power Toys newest on Windows 11 here. Try running Power Toys run with the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have run into the bug reported in
[Unable to recognize new apps #4802](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/4802).

The advice in that post was to clear the cache at
`%userprofile%/appdata/local/microsoft/powertoys/powertoys run/Cache`
and restart PowerToys Run (or reboot).

Comment: I don't have a Cache folder present at that address, but after restarting PowerToys it was able to find the renamed folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Windows Power Toys app Run Command just uses the Windows Path.

[Power Toys Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run)

```
$ control>system>admin shows all settings of the path 'Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools'.
```

Just set your Windows path as you need

You can also include the full path when you run the App